# Why is container border messing up Masonry.js placement of items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, masonry

I am using [Desandro's Masonry Library](https://masonry.desandro.com/) to get a masonry layout of my tiles.

The issue: my tiles are off by a few percentage points, hence they are overlapping and not centered, doesn't look as its supposed to. I traced the problem, or part of it at least, to the fact that my `container` has a `border` of `10px`.

In light of that, my solution was to subtract that border from the width of the tile like so `width: calc(100% - 25px);`, and also subtract the `container padding of 10px`, and `tile padding of 5px`.

This stopped the tiles from overlapping, however, still not the desired result:

[image]

--> They are not centered and there is an odd gap on the right.

Below is my `CSS`:

```css
/*Masonry*/

.mod_catalogUniversalView.masonry_list {
    &>* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    padding: 10px;
}

.ctlg_teaser {
    opacity: 0;
    float: left;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    /* vertical gutter */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}


.ctlg_teaser {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {

    .ctlg_teaser {
        width: calc(50% - 25px);
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {

    .ctlg_teaser {
        width: calc(33.33% - 25px);
    }
}
```

The `HTML`:

```html
<div class="ctlg_teaser block<?= $this->cssClass ?>">
  <div class="ctlg_entity">
    <a href="<?= $this->masterUrl ?>"></a>
    <?php if ($this->logo): ?>
      <div class="ctlg_entity_value">
        <?= $this->logo ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->name): ?>
      <h3><?= $this->name ?></h3>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->branch): ?>
      <p><?= $this->branch ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->masterUrl): ?>
      <a class="read_more" href="<?= $this->masterUrl ?>" title="<?= $this->title ?>">Mehr Details</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

And `JS`:

```js
    /* Tiles Masonry*/
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var grid = $('.mod_catalogUniversalView.masonry_list').imagesLoaded(function() {
            grid.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.ctlg_teaser',
                percentPosition: true
            });
            $('.ctlg_teaser').css('opacity', '1');
        });
    });
```

I have also made a [CodePem](https://codepen.io/pw17l008/pen/WNbgEVr) that recreates the issue!

Any input is highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What is the purpose of the borders? Are they there to create some space between the tiles? In that case you can use the `gutter` option in Masonry described [here](https://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#gutter).

Comment: @volt All the borders, the `container` and the `tiles`, are part of the design that I have to implement.  I have created the `gutter` by adding `padding` on the `tiles`. Using the 'gutter' option works too, but the issue persists. Something, I can't figure out what, keeps pushing the tiles to the left. I noticed when I resize the window, initially it fits, then the tiles settle into position with a minimal push to the left.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to figure out what the issue is without being able to look at a full working example. Please consider creating a working snippet that mimics the situation you have going on your site.

Comment: @volt Here is a CodePen: https://codepen.io/pw17l008/pen/WNbgEVr

Comment: @volt Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to wrap your `.masonry__list` within a **container**, and move your styling of border and etc. from `.masonry__list` to the **container**.

This is because when you apply Masonry on the `.masonry__list`, Masonry is trying to measure the height and width of the content, and inject its own styling to maintain the height of the `.masonry__list`. This would potentially cause your `.masonry__list` layout to be gone.

See the updated Codepen here extended from yours:

https://codepen.io/cosmiccommand/pen/LYVWKqK

```css
.container {
    border: solid 10px red;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;

  &, * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="masonry__list">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </div>
</div>
```